# Optimal Prior Probabilities Linear Discriminant Analysis (In R)

Tags: r, binary-data

I have a dataset where there are two outcomes "Severe" and "Nonsevere".

I want to find the optimal values for the prior probabilities for LDA to minimize the error rate and number misclassified.

```
lda.obj <- lda(severity ~ ., data = liver, prior=c(p2,p1)) 
Pred.obj <- predict(lda.obj, liver)
(Table3 <- table(Pred.obj$class, liver$severity))
```

This gets me the miss classification table.

```
      Nonsevere Severe
  Nonsevere       168     70
  Severe           32     75
```

This gets me the total amount of errors which I want to minimize.

```
sum(Pred.obj$class != liver$severity)
```

Now, I can enter various for p1 and p2 and call each of my functions but that is tedious and I was wondering if there was a way to display graphically all the error rates for every possible value of p1 and p2 to get the optimal prior probabilities.

Comment: So which is it? You want to minimize the number or the proportion misidentified?

Comment: The number and proportion misidentified should lead to similar results in this case because n is constant.  I guess proportion is more convenient though.

Comment: Were you ever able to get an answer for this? I have a similar problem and haven't found a  solution yet.